# Create a matrix from a dataframe and fill it with the count of a column according to rows

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, count

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(teams=c("A", "A", "C", "C", "D", "D"), 
             country=c("Italy","Italy","Italy","Italy", "India","India"),
             players=c("ac","bd","fg","ji","ki","yr"), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to create a matrix as follows:

[image]

Basically, "teams" and "country" should be the rows and columns of the matrix respectively and the values should be the count of the names of the players.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  count(teams, country) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  teams Italy India
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 A         2     0
2 C         2     0
3 D         0     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am getting an error "Error in count(., teams, country) : object 'teams' not found". I am unsure as to why I am getting such an error.

Comment: I am unsure either unless you are working on a different data frame than the one you provided above.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.matrix(table(df$teams, df$country))
  #   India Italy
  # A     0     2
  # C     0     2
  # D     2     0

# If order matters
df$country <- factor(df$country, levels=c("Italy", "India"))
as.matrix(table(df$teams, df$country))
  #   Italy India
  # A     2     0
  # C     2     0
  # D     0     2
```